# How to download attachment from rally using perl

Tags: perl, rally

I am completely new to this area.
Currently am working on an automation script, as part of it i need to download attachments from rally defect records to my local machine, process and attach it in an email.
Please help on how to download an attachment from rally using PERL.

PS: i need to run this script for huge list of defect records.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a perl solution but you may learn from MarkW's Ruby script [here](https://github.com/markwilliams970/Rally-Export-Attachments). It is based on Rally [Ruby API toolkit](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby). There is no perl equivalent.